# printf not working after executing external function

Tags: c, cobol

I have the following c code which calls a cobol program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libcob.h"
//#pragma linkage (verkoop, COBOL)

extern void VERKOOP(char *productid, char *aantal, char*resultaat);

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int return_status;
    COB_RTD = cob_get_rtd();
    char *productid = "20    ";
    char *aantal = "000020";
    char resultaat[30];
    cob_init(rtd, 0, NULL);
    printf("hallo");//prints
    VERKOOP(productid, aantal, resultaat);
    printf("hallo");//doesn't print
    printf("resultaat:%s", resultaat);// doesn't print
    cob_stop_run (rtd, return_status);
}
```

I'm using the printf to see if resultaat has been assigned correctly. However, both of the lines after VERKOOP don't print for some reason.

This is the COBOL code of VERKOOP(he does fill in LS-RESULTAAT correctly here, I tried it with DISPLAY and this part works):

```
*************************************************************
* VERKOOP  
*************************************************************
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. VERKOOP.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT PRODUCTEN ASSIGN TO "BESTANDEN/LIJSTPRODUCTEN"
           ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM
           ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
           RECORD KEY IS PRODUCTID
           FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  PRODUCTEN BLOCK CONTAINS 10 RECORDS.
       01  PRODUCT.
           02 PRODUCTID PIC X(6).
           02 LEVERANCIERID PIC X(6).
           02 AANTAL PIC 9(6).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77  FOUT PIC X.
           88 PRODUCT-NIET-GEVONDEN VALUE 1.
       77 WS-PRODUCTID PIC X(6).
       77 WS-AANTAL PIC 9(6).
       77 WS-FILE-STATUS PIC XX.
       77 WS-RESULTAAT PIC X(30).
       LINKAGE SECTION.
       01 LS-PRODUCTID PIC X(6).
       01 LS-AANTAL PIC 9(6).
       01 LS-RESULTAAT PIC X(30).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LS-PRODUCTID, LS-AANTAL, LS-RESULTAAT.

       MAIN.
           PERFORM INITIALISEER
           PERFORM LEES-PRODUCT-IN
           PERFORM LEES-BESTAND
           PERFORM SLUIT-BESTAND
           STOP RUN.

       INITIALISEER.
           OPEN I-O PRODUCTEN.
*          DISPLAY WS-FILE-STATUS..

       LEES-PRODUCT-IN.
           MOVE LS-PRODUCTID TO WS-PRODUCTID
           MOVE LS-AANTAL TO WS-AANTAL
           MOVE 'OK' TO WS-RESULTAAT
*          DISPLAY WS-RESULTAAT
           MOVE WS-RESULTAAT TO LS-RESULTAAT.       
*          DISPLAY "GEEF PRODUCTID OP: "
*          ACCEPT WS-PRODUCTID
*          DISPLAY "GEEF AANTAL OP: "
*          ACCEPT WS-AANTAL.

       LEES-BESTAND.
*      DISPLAY "LEES-BESTAND"
       MOVE WS-PRODUCTID TO PRODUCTID
*      DISPLAY PRODUCTID
*      DISPLAY WS-FILE-STATUS
       READ PRODUCTEN INVALID KEY SET PRODUCT-NIET-GEVONDEN TO TRUE
       END-READ 
       IF PRODUCT-NIET-GEVONDEN PERFORM FOUTJE    
       ELSE 
*      MOVE WS-PRODUCTID TO PRODUCTID
       SUBTRACT WS-AANTAL FROM AANTAL   
       PERFORM UPDATE-PRODUCT
       END-IF.


      UPDATE-PRODUCT.
        REWRITE PRODUCT INVALID KEY PERFORM FOUTJE.

        SLUIT-BESTAND.
*       DISPLAY "SLUIT-BESTAND"
           CLOSE PRODUCTEN.

        FOUTJE.
           DISPLAY "ER IS EEN FOUT OPGETREDEN"
           DISPLAY WS-FILE-STATUS
           STOP RUN.
```

UPDATE: I tried removing both "STOP RUN's", however now for some reason he substracts 40 instead of 20 and prints "ER IS EEN FOUT OPGETREDEN". So he is running the COBOL Program twice for some reason.

UPDATE: After replacing STOP RUN by GOBACK it works perfectly

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, and i´ve no idea of cobol, but what happens if you add linebreaks (\n) after the text of both printf?

Comment: it prints newlines like intended

Comment: Perhaps the linkage is such that the stack has been corrupted by `VERKOOP`.  Try it with a debugger or comparing the object code between the COBOL routine and a sample one in C.

Comment: @RobinHellemans, deviantfan's suggestion would effectively flush the `stdout` buffer.  It's necessary if you're relying solely on the `printf`'s output to determine the path of execution.  It's definitely a step in the right direction, but a debugger would be the next logical step.

Comment: I've already suggested you replace at least the main STOP RUN by GOBACK or EXIT PROGRAM. Also I suggested you use the COBOL-IT API for C/COBOL (COBOL-IT COBOL that is) intercommunication. What happened?

Comment: EXIT PROGRAM gives the same error, the program runs twice, however GOBACK did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your STOP RUN is returning here, cob_stop_run (rtd, return_status), so your prior code after the invocation of the COBOL program does not run.

If EXIT PROGRAM is in a "main" program (at least in the case of the pragma-usage it seems that is what you have) then it is treated the same as STOP RUN.

GOBACK is returning control to where you expect it to.

If you use the COBOL-IT API, as has already been suggested, then perhaps the EXIT PROGRAM will behave differently. Perhaps not.

You are using an undocumented way to call a COBOL-IT program. Exactly how it behaves is not known, and cannot be known, to someone without COBOL-IT and the same operating system as you have, and the patience to do something in a non-obvious way.

If things are suggested which you then ignore, it is difficult to keep answering your questions.

Again, you have an Assignment. The Assignment expects you to use the API. You should use the API and get your programs working. If you have time later, you can look at the pragma-usage to effect the interoperability.